# dll files for creating a setup

Tags: mysql, c++builder

I 'm working on an application using rad studio 2009 (c++) and mySQL. I want to build a setup so I can set up my application and on other PCs without installing and rad studio. As far as I 've searched, I will need some dlls. Does anyone know what dlls? I couldn't find out...
please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++ Builder if you don't use runtime packages and you link against the static RTL then you don't need to supply anything beyond the compiled .exe.

I couldn't say what you need for the database connection, but I imagine it is documented and Johan has provided you with an answer that addresses this part of your question.

Dependency Walker can be used to investigate the dependencies.

Comment: @johan that's not what I meant. That's why I said "I couldn't say what you
need for the database connection."

Answer (score 1):

You need `libmySQL.dll`
and if you're using dbExpress you'll also need: `dbxmys.dll`

If you're using ZEOS you'll only need the libMySQL.dll, but AFAIK only ZEOS 7 alpha works in Unicode Delphi/C++ Builder

Be careful to make **sure** `libMySQL.dll` is is the exact version that goes with the MySQL server you are connecting against.

Comment: @Olga, C++ builder will accept Delphi files, so yes Zeos 7 Alpha will work, but the **Alpha** status should be a warning. If you're just playing it works as far as I've tested, but for production I would not trust it.